# Parsing output of EXPLAIN command in PostgreSQL

Tags: parsing, postgresql, sql-execution-plan

I'm developing an application that requires parsing of execution plans (those produced as output by issuing an EXPLAIN [query] command). Are you aware of any Java library that I could use for this purpose? I found https://github.com/depesz/Pg--Explain but it is built in Perl.

Also another option I am considering is to use EXPLAIN [query] FORMAT XML which is available in PostgreSQL 9.1. However, in that case it would better to have the XML Schema of the generated plans available.

Is there any other solution I am not aware of?

Comment: The stuff Hugo Depesz has built is pretty fantastic. I doubt you'll find much else, and certainly nothing better. Can't you just call his modules as a web wervice or so?

Comment: Note that the XML output was added in 9.0, not 9.1

Comment: FWIW there's also support for output in JSON and YAML format.

Comment: @C.Ramseyer **Hubert** "Depesz" Lubaczewski

Answer (score 4):

You've got the right answer right there. For your automated needs use XML or the tools at:
https://github.com/depesz/Pg--Explain

For the rest of us, the interactive version is a real gem, and I'm posting it here so people find it:
http://explain.depesz.com/

Background on explain itself is at:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html
But there does not appear to be a reference to a DTD or defined schema for explain.

Comment: This can be helpful also if someone needs to parse depesz site output: https://github.com/celuk/tpcds-postgres#getting-graphs-from-analyzed-texts

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement of parsing XML plan output of Explain command. I have used LibXML2 libray. It is easy to use and powerful. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar requirement and solved by `psql` and `jq`, for example:

```sh
psql $PG_URL -P pager=off -Aqt -c 'EXPLAIN (FORMAT JSON) SELECT version()' | jq
```

You can also pipe to other programming languages you are familiar with, for example:

```sh
psql $PG_URL -P pager=off -Aqt -c 'EXPLAIN (FORMAT JSON) SELECT version()' |
  ruby -rjson -e 'pp JSON.parse($stdin.read)'
```

**References**

- [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/app-psql.html)
- [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)